# Problem with algorithm(ic) and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, subfloats, algorithms, incompatibility

The following code works ... fine!

```
\documentclass{book}

% \usepackage{subfig}
% \usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
We outline this in Algorithm~\ref{alg1}.
%%
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algo}
\label{alg1}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \STATE A
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

But once I add either `subfig` or `subcaption` to it as hinted, I get the warning

```
name{algorithm.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

and the link to the algorithm does not work. Note that the code does not make use of any feature of `subfig`, or `subcaption`. It must come from some macro redefinition in those packages. After searching around I found [algorithmic-fix](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showpost.php?s=fb8cdcbc5cb33e8010c877bd33f91378&p=258363&postcount=6) from our @AxelSommerfeldt, but that does not fix the warning. (Strangely, it is also not needed when `subfig` and `subcaption` are out.)

What do I overlook?

Comment: have you tried loading `hyperref` after the other packages? I'd avoid `subfig` and use `subcaption`

Comment: @cmhughes The hyperref manual said somewhere that `algorithm` should be loaded after `hyperref`.

Comment: I get no error with either package (not both, of course).

Comment: I also get no error- have you seen [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: Loading `hyperref` after `algorithm` is still the wrong load order. However, with up-to-date TeX systems it should compile fine anyway, but only because Heiko (Oberdiek) and I have implemented extra code in `hyperref` and `caption` to handle such wrong load orders. See also: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=20075

Comment: ...and my answer.

Comment: So I get the warning, as I have `caption` 3.2, and `hyperref` 6.83. With newer versions the problem should go away.

Comment: @mafp ...or you could correct the package load order. (Wherever applicable this is the best solution anyway.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a copy-paste-answer originating at http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=20075:

**by myself on Fri Apr 20th, 2012**

The correct load order of `algorithm` and `hyperref` is:

```
\usepackage{float}  % load float package first!
...
\usepackage{hyperref} % let hyperref patch the float package stuff
...
\usepackage{algorithm} % let algorithm use the patched version of the float package
```

See `hyperref` README for details.

**by myself on Thu Apr 26th, 2012**

I have examined this case a little further. Why is the (wrong) behavior with `caption` package different to the (wrong, too) behavior without `caption` package?

The answer:

If `hyperref` is loaded after the `float` package, it patches two macros offered (or patched) by the float package: `\@caption` and `\float@makebox`. If `hyperref` is loaded before the `float` package, these two patches are missing.

If the `caption` package is loaded additionally, the `caption` package patches `\@caption`, too. (And the code offered by the `caption` package is adapted to both, `float` and `hyperref` package.) So when the load order is `caption`-`hyperref`-`float`, only one patch is missing in this case, the one `hyperref` does for `\float@makebox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 

\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption} % Loaded by Thesis.cls
\usepackage{hyperref}                     % Loaded by Thesis.cls

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatletter
% Patch of \float@makebox, taken from hyperref.sty [2012/02/28 v6.82p]
%% DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME, USE CORRECT LOAD ORDER OF PACKAGES INSTEAD!
  \let\HyOrg@float@makebox\float@makebox
  \renewcommand{\float@makebox}[1]{%
    ... (Code removed)
  }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Iris Detection Algorithm}\label{alg:myaaa}
...
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{Two}

See Algorithm~\ref{alg:myaaa}.

\end{document}
```

So without `caption` package we have two missing patches (usually done by the `hyperref` package if the package load order would be correct), with `caption` package we have one missing patch. This leads to the different behavior, wrong in both cases, but wrong in a different way.

**by myself on Wed Jan 9th, 2013**

Update:

Heiko Oberdiek (Maintainer of the `hyperref` package) and me decided to implement a workaround for this incorrect load order `hyperref`-`float` within our packages since this is a very common mistake.

So when using at least version 6.82q of the `hyperref` package and version 3.3 of the `caption` package the wrong load order should not make any harm anymore.

Please note that this will not correct other incorrect load orders regarding the `hyperref` package (see README provided by `hyperref`), just the only one "hyperref before float", and it will only correct it if the `caption` package is used additionally.

**NOTE** These are only excerpts of http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=20075 and I have only copied postings of mine, not the ones from other people. So if you are interested in the whole story (and how my cat is looking), follow the link.

Comment: Thanks, I should have found that myself. How does `algorithmic-fix` fit into this? Is this obsolete?

Comment: @mafp `algorithm` does (only) define the floating environment with the help of the `float` package, and when this happens in a wrong order, it will cause the "has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one" warning, and this is what the answer of mine is about. `algorithmic` does define a (non-floating) environment for typesetting algorithms, and this package still has `hyperref` issues since the author of the package has not fixed them. So in short: No, `algorithmic-fix` is (unfortunately) not obsolete, it fixes (other) problems which (unfortunately) still exists.